# PhantomJS not loading .js from same URL

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

The javascript is located on the same website that I'm opening.

Example: `http://test.site.com`

js => `http://test.site.com/cache/6343019445fb7d95bd2bd09c5bbfb002.js`

I'm also including jQuery from googleapis and that appears to load! I tried getting some data from events like [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/content.html) but nothing shows up.

This is my test code:

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = {
  width: 1366, 
  height: 720
};

page.settings.loadImages = true;
page.settings.localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled = true;
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;
page.settings.webSecurityEnabled = false;
page.settings.XSSAuditingEnabled = false;

var uri = 'http://test.site.com';

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
  console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
};
page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
  console.log('Unable to load resource (#' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
  console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
};
page.onResourceTimeout = function(request) {
  console.log('Response (#' + request.id + '): ' + JSON.stringify(request));
};
page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
  var msgStack = ['ERROR: ' + msg];
  if (trace && trace.length) {
    msgStack.push('TRACE:');
    trace.forEach(function(t) {
      msgStack.push(' -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function "' + t.function +'")' : ''));
    });
  }
  console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
};

page.onLoadFinished = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(page.content); // <script> is there
    console.log('render');    
    page.render('test.png');
    phantom.exit();  
  }, 4000);

};

page.open(uri, function() {
  console.log('loaded');
});
```

I see no other console messages besides `render`, `loaded` and the page content.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think .js is not loaded? There are no checks for that in the code.

Comment: I added some messages in the .js file and they are not shown through `onConsoleMessage`. Also that js should do visible changes to the document which they should reflect in the screenshot, but they aren't

Comment: I'm seeing the js file in the `onResourceReceived` event, so apparently it's downloaded but for some reason it's not executed ?!

Comment: Ok I found that the problem is somewhere in the .js file code. Browser shows no errors or warnings, neither does phantomjs through the `onError` event... My only choice now is to eliminate parts of the code gradually and see which of them causes this issue :(

Comment: I suspect that you're running PhantomJS 2.x. It is known to hide errors, so you should try it with PhantomJS 1.9.8.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to evaluate the page. I believe it's something like this.

```
page.evaluate(function () {
    // This is after page is evaluated and javascript is run
});
```

Note that evaluate doesn't give you access to the JS functions or variables, it only runs it for you. If you need to do access the JS code from Phantom, you'll want to put the JavaScript code inside the `page.evaluate` yourself so that you can `console.log` or manipulate as you need to.

Comment: That's only useful for running a function in the page's context. But I tried it to test if console.log's work and to see if my script functions are there and they are not. But I see `window.jQuery`...

Comment: I'm very rusty on phantom JS, but I believe evaluate doesn't give you access to the JS functions or variables, it only runs it for you. If you need to do that, you'll want to just put the javascript code inside the `page.evaluate` yourself so that you can `console.log` or manipulate as you need to..